# "Far apart" vs "Far away" (about comparing two objects)

Tags: spoken-english

Are "far away" and "far apart" interchangeable in this context:

```
  A <--------->B
```

> A and B are **far apart** from each other.
>
> A and B are **far away** from each other.

Are "apart" and "away" interchangeable here?

Comment: I find "far apart from each other" to be odd. I would expect just "far apart", which means exactly the same.

Comment: @ColinFine , so would you expect: "A and B are apart" and "A and B are far away from each other"? (And can it be: "A and B are far away"?)

Comment: To the first, yes; but "apart" and "far apart" are quite different. "Apart" could be far, but tends to be quite close. As for the second question: "A and B are far away" is perfectly grammatical, but means "from me, or the reference point we've been talking about", not "from each other".

Answer (score 2):

In this sense, yes. "Far apart" is always used when comparing two specified places or things. "Far away" can have one of the things implied, usually the speaker's or listener's location.

> - Chicago is far away. (implied "from here")
> - Far away, across the sea, lived a giant.
> - They traveled far away.

In those senses "far away" means basically "a long distance". "Far apart" cannot be used in that manner.

Comment: I think your last example must be a typo for "_They_ traveled far away."

Comment: Oops, yes,I'll fix it.

Comment: So in this context can both "far apart" amd "far away" natural?

Comment: @it's Yes. In the examples in the question, both are quite natural, and have the same meaning. I see no difference even of emphasis or implication in the two examples.

Comment: So can " A and B are far apart from each other" be used as well instead of "A and B are far apart"? (Colin Fine didn't find it natural...)

Comment: @Its " A and B are far apart from each other" is redundant, because "far apart" implies "from each other", and so that form is less common, but I don't see it as unnatural. Note the implication is only a default: "A and B are far apart from C." says that both A and B are a long distance from C.

Comment: And does "far away" give you an impression of talking about the distances by taking one particular thing as reference?

Comment: @it's When "far away" is followed by "from" whatever follows "from" is the referent. If "from" is omitted, then the . implied or default referent is often "from here", the position of the speaker,  or possibly "from you" or "from the starting place" (of a trip, say)